# Large memory overhead of decoding Text objects

Tags: haskell

I'm doing some `Binary` serializing and deserializing of `Text` objects, and I noticed that an un-decoded thunk uses **much** more memory than the actual length of the data. I've created a toy program that reproduces the problem (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/danielkeller/c19a740fc2b0df861343) for the complete setup):

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.Text as T

main = do
    handle <- openBinaryFile "testfile" ReadMode
    initSize <- hFileSize handle
    str <- B.hGet handle (fromInteger initSize)
    hClose handle
    --msgs :: [T.Text]
    let (_, msgs) = decodeMany str
    --here we fool the GC into retaining the thunks in msgs
    chr <- readLn
    print $ map (max chr) $ map (T.foldl1 max) msgs
    --now we let it collect them
    num1 <- readLn
    print (num1 + 1)
```

and when I run it:

```
$ ./Test2 +RTS -S
    Alloc    Copied     Live    GC    GC     TOT     TOT  Page Flts
    bytes     bytes     bytes  user  elap    user    elap
   108112      6936     82320  0.00  0.01    0.01    0.33    0    0  (Gen:  1)
     1720      6152     73400  0.00  0.00    0.02    0.66    0    0  (Gen:  1)
't'
   874672     28544    408856  0.00  0.00    0.02    4.14    0    0  (Gen:  0) **
   519864     33200    434680  0.00  0.00    0.02    4.14    0    0  (Gen:  0) **
"vxvxvvvxvxvvvxvxvvvxvxvvvxvxvvvxvxvvx"
    95504      8424     83680  0.00  0.00    0.02    4.45    0    0  (Gen:  1)
8
9
    30992      6984     65824  0.00  0.00    0.02    6.48    0    0  (Gen:  1)
```

So it takes over 300k (see `**` marked lines) to store 18k of text. (I've checked the heap profile, and they're mostly `ARR_WORDS`.)

On the other hand, if I replace `T.foldl1` with `T.foldl1'`, the garbage collector is able to reclaim the thunks, and the marked lines become

```
   781336      8432     83680  0.00  0.00    0.02    6.48    0    0  (Gen:  1)
```

So it allocates about as much, but reclaims it once the `Text` objects have been forced. I imagine some combination of the way I do i/o and the types I use causes it to make a full copy of the file for every decoded string (since 37 strings * 18k = 666k).

**How do I keep the decoding process from allocating and retaining so much memory?**

Comment: why you are not using [`hGetContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:hGetContents)? if you want to read the _entire_ file (`hFileSize handle`) and then close the handle (`hClose handle`) why are you using `ByteString.Lazy`?

Comment: @behzad.nouri In my actual code, I also write to the file. Also, `Binary` only works with lazy bytestrings.

Comment: It seems like you already have the answer in your question - eliminate excess laziness by using strict functions and datatypes, like `foldl1'` instead of `foldl1`. This has very little to do with copying, most likely, more with excess laziness. If you want to make sure some value is evaluated at most once, for example `map (T.foldl1 max) msgs`, you should assign it to a variable - the compiler doesn't, in general, perform such optimizations by itself. The value will be evaluated the first time it is used, and never again.